# Calculate Thread.Sleep() for bitrate limit

Tags: .net, algorithm, baud-rate

I have a class reading a http stream file.

```
    static  long CurrentMilliseconds { get { return Environment.TickCount; } }
    public void ReadFile()
    {
        ...
        while(true)
        {
            int r = stm.Read(buf, 0, bufSize);
            if(r == 0) break;
            ...
            int x= CalculateDelay()
            Thread.Sleep(x);
        }
    }
```

Let's say I download 5 files in parallel (5 instances of this class running) and I want *total bitrate<800 kb/s*

I have difficulty calculating delay x. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the exact steps to do it, but I would break down the problem in parts. The first thing you need to do is figure out the current bitrate for each instance, then you sum up the total, then you check that total against your limit value. If the total is more than your limit (800 kb/s) then increase the delay, if it is less then decrease the delay.

Answer (score 2):

```
double downloadDurationInSec = ...; //provide this
long bytesTransferred = ...; //provide this
double targetBytesPerSec = 800 * 1000;
double targetDurationInSec = bytesTransferred / targetBytesPerSec;
if (targetDurationInSec < downloadDurationInSec) {
 double sleepTimeInSec = downloadDurationInSec - targetDurationInSec;
 Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sleepTimeInSec));
}
```

Note the expressive variable naming which includes the units.

The idea of the algorithm is to calculate how long the download *should* have taken up to the current point. If it was faster than it should have, sleep the difference.

This is numerically stable because you don't incrementally update any variables.